# How to use AutoMapper.Data with SqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, automapper

I'm trying to find an updated sample for mapping an **SqlDataReader** object into custom one.

```
 Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationUtil.ConnectionStrings("xxxx").ConnectionString
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader
 Dim a As AAAA
     Try
         Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
             Using cm As New SqlCommand
                 cm.Connection = cn
                 cn.Open()
                 cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                 cm.CommandText = "qf.AAAAGet"
                 cm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AAAAId", aaaaId))
                 Dim prmRV As New SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
                 prmRV.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
                 cm.Parameters.Add(prmRV)

                 dr = cm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
```

I would like to map **dr** into say **ACustomObject**  (which contains all the fields with the exact names returned in the **dr**)

1. How do i configure such a mapper ?
2. How do i call map ?

my thoughts are :
- In **Global.asax** call a static method to do the init/config
- After i'm executing the query do the mapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Global.asax you config the map such this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(Sub(cfg)
                      MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(New AutoMapper.Data.DataReaderMapper With { .YieldReturnEnabled = True })
                  End Sub)

Mapper.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, YourClass)
```

and in exeucute code (result is As IEnumerable(Of YourClass)):

```
Dim results = Mapper.Map(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of YourClass))(dataReaderInstance)
```

an helper method for all your need:

```
Class DataReaderMapper(Of YourClass)
    Shared Sub New()
        Mapper.Initialize(Sub(cfg) MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(New AutoMapper.Data.DataReaderMapper() With { .YieldReturnEnabled = True }) 
        Mapper.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, YourClass)()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetRecordes(reader As IDataReader) As IEnumerable(Of YourClass)
        Return Mapper.Map(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of YourClass))(reader)
    End Function
End Class
```